Unable to mock repository for unit tests in NestJS
Background
I'm woking on a NestJS project with the following file structure (note: I've skipped the modules not needed for the question).
src/scim
├── custom-attributes
│   ├── custom-attributes.module.ts
├── markets
│   ├── markets.entity.ts
│   ├── markets.module.ts
│   └── markets.service.ts
├── scim-tenants
│   ├── scim-tenants.entity.ts
│   ├── scim-tenants.module.ts
│   ├── scim-tenants.service.spec.ts
│   └── scim-tenants.service.ts
├── scim.module.ts
├── users
│   ├── users.module.ts

The markets entity is something that has been a recent addition to the code, the entity is used in the market service to get a market by Id. Both have been registered in the markets.module.ts.
Here's the entity and its usage:

markets.entity.ts

import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('markets')
export class Markets {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'market_id' })
  marketId: number;

  @Column({ name: 'name' })
  name: string;
}


markets.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class MarketsService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Markets) private marketsRepository: Repository<Markets>) {}

  private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(MarketsService.name);

  /**
   * Finds a branch by its ID.
   * @param branchId - The branch ID to search for.
   * @returns A promise resolving to the branch entity or undefined if not found.
   */
  async findBranchByBranchId(branchId: number) {
    return await this.marketsRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        marketId: branchId,
      },
    });
  }
}


markets module:

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Markets])],
  providers: [MarketsService],
  exports: [MarketsService],
})
export class MarketsModule {}

Now, The markets module is called in CustomAttributesModule. When I run the dev server, everything works as expected, my code is able to fetch the market repository and get the data.
Question
When working on unit tests for the above code, I am having issues mocking the repository. Here's a snippet from the unit tests:
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        ScimTenantsService,
        MarketsService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          useClass: Repository,
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(ScimTenant),
          useClass: Repository,
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Markets),
          useClass: Repository,
        },
      ],
      imports: [CustomAttributesModule],
    }).compile();

Before adding the MarketsService all tests used to run fine. The code was able to mock the User and ScimTenant repos. But with Markets, it throws the following error:
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MarketsRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - Is TypeOrmModule a valid NestJS module?
    - If DataSource is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
    - If DataSource is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing DataSource */ ]
      })

      26 |
      27 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    > 28 |     const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
         |                                   ^
      29 |       providers: [
      30 |         UsersService,
      31 |         ScimTenantsService,

      at TestingInjector.lookupComponentInParentModules (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:247:19)
      at TestingInjector.resolveComponentInstance (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:200:33)
      at TestingInjector.resolveComponentInstance (../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-injector.js:19:45)
      at resolveParam (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:120:38)
          at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at TestingInjector.resolveConstructorParams (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:135:27)
      at TestingInjector.loadInstance (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:61:13)
      at TestingInjector.loadProvider (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:88:9)
      at TestingInjector.lookupComponentInImports (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:281:17)
      at TestingInjector.lookupComponentInParentModules (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:245:33)
      at TestingInjector.resolveComponentInstance (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:200:33)
      at TestingInjector.resolveComponentInstance (../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-injector.js:19:45)
      at resolveParam (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:120:38)
          at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at TestingInjector.resolveConstructorParams (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:135:27)
      at TestingInjector.loadInstance (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:61:13)
      at TestingInjector.loadProvider (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:88:9)
      at ../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:56:13
          at async Promise.all (index 3)
      at TestingInstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:55:9)
      at ../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:40:13
          at async Promise.all (index 3)
      at TestingInstanceLoader.createInstances (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:39:9)
      at TestingInstanceLoader.createInstancesOfDependencies (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:22:13)
      at TestingInstanceLoader.createInstancesOfDependencies (../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-instance-loader.js:9:9)
      at TestingModuleBuilder.createInstancesOfDependencies (../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js:97:9)
      at TestingModuleBuilder.compile (../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js:63:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (scim/users/users.service.spec.ts:28:35)

My question is, what is different in MarketService that it is not being mocked like other entities/repositories. The way of declaring the MarketsServices is same as others. I've tried to mirror the same. Also is the way I am using the right way to mock? (Keeping in mind, there are unit tests, so we don't need a DB connection)
